# Site validation throws an error: there is no attribute "DATA-BG"

Tags: javascript, css, validation

Validating my website under development, which [can be viewed here](http://www.class-a-studio.co.il/test01.php), I'm receiving the error message: Line 92, Column 32: there is no attribute "DATA-BG". I'm using data-attributes like this throughout my site:

```
<div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="slider/images/4.jpg">
```

So, the data-bg attibute is not recognised. I'd like to know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your [DOCTYPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration), which is currently set as:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

The W3C validator looks at the DOCTYPE declaration when determining what type of validation to perform. HTML attributes that begin `data-` are an HTML5 idea, so you'll need to change your DOCTYPE to HTML5 so it validates as correct.

Comment: So to make it work I should replace all the site code to HTML5 or have a simple way to overcome
This problem?

Comment: It looks like the code is working as is, but to make it validate, yes, you'll have to update your DOCTYPE. That may have other unintended consequences though, as the DOCTYPE plays a large role in how IE chooses to display a website. Test it and see how it affects the output. You should start using the HTML5 or XHTML Strict DOCTYPEs for all new websites you create though… It will force IE to render in "standards mode" and make life easier for you :-p

Comment: All is well in IE7 IE9 only in IE8 there is a problem with the slide going down.
Replace the site code (currently) HTML5 format will promote the site ... so it's not out of the question.

I WAS think THAT I can replace the command "DATA-BG" By order of CSS or something else - in order that it will be approved by the WC3?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to take so long to get back to you. The script you're using (http://www.class-a-studio.co.il/slider/js/jquery.bgImageMenu.js) uses `.data('bg')` to get the properties several times. It's not just a matter of defining the background in the CSS… the JS needs to know the URL too, and that's how it's getting the URL now. If you want to change the way it gets the URL, you'll have to make some major modifications to the Javascript, and you'll need a new scheme for how to pass those URLs to the Javascript. The `data-` attribute syntax is useful for passing the information.

Answer (score 0):

The `data-` attributes are not allowed according to HTML 4.01 doctype, or any a published doctype, This has no impact on their functionality; it is just a syntactic matter.

Options:

1. Just ignore the message. This gets impractical if you have loads of such attributes, because then the amount of these messages makes it difficult to detect real markup errors.
2. [Construct a custom DTD](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/own-dtd.html) that allows the `data-` attribute(s) that you are using. [The W3C shouts against the idea](http://www.w3.org/Style/customdtd.en.html), but the real problem with it is that most people don’t want to get involved in DTDs, and it takes some learning to edit a DTD. In this case, you would just add your attribute(s) to the `coreattrs` attributes. You would need to add each `data-` attribute separately.
3. Change to the HTML5 doctype statement, `<!doctype html>`. This make all `data-` attributes allowed, but it also implies restrictions in other areas. HTML5 is *not* a pure extension on HTML 4.01; for example, it declares most kinds of `meta` tags invalid (and although most `meta` tags are useless, you may have some that are useful but not allowed in HTML5 at present).